# Sound output keeps getting revert back to the other "Multichannel Output - Built-in Audio" every reboot on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi, 20.10

On the sound output devices, it has 4 selection by default(at least for me). It is a Raspberry Pi 4 model B(4GB) rev 1.1:

1. Multichannel Output - Built-in Audio
2. Analog Output - Built-in Audio
3. Multichannel Output - Built-in Audio
4. Headphones - Built-in Audio

I assume that #1 and #3 represents the two mini-HDMI ports while #2 is the 2.5mm jack. Though I have no idea where #4's output is. Anyway, it is always set to #3 every time I start/reboot my device but the only one that has sounds is #1. I tried to use the other mini-HDMI port but the result stays the same - it is always on #3 every reboot but the actual output is on #1.

I saw some probable fixes but those are from old versions and I'm trying to figure out how to fix this without resolving to command lines just to force it to stay on that output device. I'll also make it connect to a bluetooth speaker later and I prefer to make it remember the last device I set it on.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround described [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/touch-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg316816.html) solved the problem.

Solution is removing the following lines from **/etc/pulse/default.pa**

```
# Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif
```